# How to stop background-image transition being cut short by mouse leaving too quickly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image, mouseover

I currently have an image div which has its background image change when I hover over a certain trigger div using jQuery's css() method.  I have a transition of 0.6s ease applied to the image div so that it smoothly fades from image to image.  However, if I move between the trigger divs too quickly, the background image immediately jumps to the next one and does not have a smooth fade.

I'm relatively new to JS and jQuery and am looking for a solution that will be able to handle quick mouse movement so that when the mouse exits one trigger div, the next background image begins to smoothly fade in even if the transition from the last mouse movement did not yet finish.  Here's the fiddle (please don't mind the strange images I used): [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nolder/g79r9krj/)

Code:

```js
$('.hover').hover(function() {
 $('#image').css('background-image', $(this).attr('data-attribute'));
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 0;
}

.hover {
 height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
 font-size: 14px;
 display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #f92;
}

#two {
  background-color: rgba(25, 140, 230, 1);
}

#three {
  background-color: #2cf;
}

#four {
  background-color: #f46;
}

#image {
 height: 400px;
 background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/x37ckzO.jpg');
 width: 400px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
<div class="hover" id="one" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/x37ckzO.jpg")'>Image 1</div>
<div class="hover" id="two" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/t6WWdc2.png")'>Image 2</div>
<div class="hover" id="three" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/jA36LVy.png")'>Image 3</div>
<div class="hover" id="four" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/5a5xBLH.png")'>Image 4</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to confess, I only partially understand the issue and why my solution works. What follows is the result of trial-and-error and works well in desktop/Chrome (otherwise untested).

First, the image must be initialized with a background that is none of the four desired backgrounds. If not, then the fix will not always work when returning to initial image - "Image 1".

For demonstration, I used a single white pixel that I found on facebook. You should serve your own.

```
#image {
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=742377892535530&ev=PageView&noscript=1'); /* single white pixel */
    width: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

Now, you have to engineer a *triple* change of background - two on mouseleave and one on mouseenter.

```
var $image = $('#image');
$('.hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $image.css('background-image', $(self).data('attribute')); // (1)
    }, 0);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    var self = this;
    $image.css('background-image', '');  // (2)
    setTimeout(function() {
        $image.css('background-image', $(self).data('attribute')); // (3)
    }, 0);
}).eq(0).trigger('mouseenter');
```

The three transitions are best explained in the order they occur when going from one `.hover` element to another - (2) (3) (1).

- (2) is key. It fixes the undesirable effect reported in the question (I don't really understand why!)
- (3) is a consequence of (2). Without (3) a regular 'mouseleave' (not entering another `.hover` element) would cause the bg-image to be blank (the white pixel). The timeout is necessary to allow (2) time to *bite*.
- (1) is the effect you really want. The timeout is a consequence of (3)'s timeout. (1) must be later than a preceding (3).

That's as much as I undertstand.

Finally, `.eq(0).trigger('mouseenter')` is necessary to initialize the background-image, to that of the "Image 1" button.

```js
var $image = $('#image');
$('.hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
 var self = this;
 setTimeout(function() {
  $image.css('background-image', $(self).data('attribute'));
 }, 0);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
 var self = this;
 $image.css('background-image', '');
 setTimeout(function() {
  $image.css('background-image', $(self).data('attribute'));
 }, 0);
}).eq(0).trigger('mouseenter');
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 0;
}

.hover {
 height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
 font-size: 14px;
 display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #f92;
}

#two {
  background-color: rgba(25, 140, 230, 1);
}

#three {
  background-color: #2cf;
}

#four {
  background-color: #f46;
}

#image {
height: 400px;
^background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/x37ckzO.jpg');
background-image: url('https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=742377892535530&ev=PageView&noscript=1');
width: 400px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
<div class="hover" id="one" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/x37ckzO.jpg")'>Image 1</div>
<div class="hover" id="two" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/t6WWdc2.png")'>Image 2</div>
<div class="hover" id="three" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/jA36LVy.png")'>Image 3</div>
<div class="hover" id="four" data-attribute='url("http://i.imgur.com/5a5xBLH.png")'>Image 4</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```